# How to divide aggregated values from one SQL select by aggregated value from another SQL select?

Tags: sql, count, db2, report, distinct

I want to calculate how much clients were communicated by system. Calculated as a percentage in the context of issues, in the context of groups, in the context of programs, in the context of channels for the period.

The formula is very simple:

```
F = X / Y
```

Where:

```
X - number of clients communicated by system.
```

And

```
Y - number of clients in analizing sample.
```

I have database table INTERACTIONS.

Table sample:

> ```
> datetime       | Issue | Group | ProgramID | Channel | CustomerID | Outcome
> ---------------+-------+-------+-----------+---------+------------+--------
> 20181126000001 | Sale  | Loans | P-1       | SMS     | 5          | Accept  
> 20181126000005 | Sale  | Loans | P-1       | PUSH    | 7          | Ignore  
> 20181126000010 | Sale  | Loans | P-2       | SMS     | 8          | Ignore  
> 20181126000015 | Sale  | Loans | P-3       | PUSH    | 10         | Accept
> ```

So the select for X is:

```
SELECT 
    ISSUE, GROUP, PROGRAMID, CHANNEL, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMERID) AS Customers 
FROM INTERACTIONS  
GROUP BY ISSUE, GROUP, PROGRAMID, CHANNEL 
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC, 3 ASC, 4 ASC;
```

The select for Y is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMERID) AS Customers 
FROM INTERACTIONS;
```

**How to combine these two SQL selects and get report with F=X/Y ?**

I want to get result something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
     ISSUE, GROUP, PROGRAMID, CHANNEL, 
     COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMERID)/
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMERID) FROM 
     INTERACTIONS) AS Customers 
FROM INTERACTIONS  
GROUP BY ISSUE, GROUP, PROGRAMID, CHANNEL
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC, 3 ASC, 4 ASC
```

Just you need to place that Y query in your X query